# How do I create interactive grass like this?

Tags: physics

I would really like to create grass that reacts to the player's movements, so when they walk through, it moves away from them, just like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Gc-Ue9_xgk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tFgyc8iykLk

The problem is, I'm not sure if this is a case of **animation, combined with some form of physics**, or **controlled by a script**. The grass looks like 2 planes that are crossing each other and originally I was going to try a LookAtPlayer script, however that would just make the planes spin around to face the player, instead of swaying in the wind, or swaying away from the player when they walk past them.

Any advice on how to create something like this with grass?

Comment: A popular way to handle animation of large swaths of vegetation is to do it in the vertex shader, pushing the vertices around just before they're rasterized onto the screen, using inputs like the player position or a render target that represents nearby pushing influences as a vector field. [This GDC talk on vertex shader techniques in Uncharted 4 shows how they applied this](https://gdcvault.com/play/1024103/Technical-Art-Techniques-of-Naughty), starting with wind animation then moving on to player interaction around 17 minutes in.

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, I'm checking out the video now! :D Also can this be applied to Unity as well as Unreal Engine? I only have experience with Unity for my big project :)

Comment: Both engines have vertex shaders that you can control or write yourself.